# CALayer: Confused about the contentsAreFlipped property

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, quartz-core

I'm confused about the `CALayer` `contentsAreFlipped` property. According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/contentsAreFlipped):

> If the layer needs to flip its content, it returns `YES` from this
>   method and applies a y-flip transform to the graphics context before
>   passing it to the layer’s `drawInContext:` method.

I'm making a custom `CALayer`, overriding `drawInContext:`. So do I need to manually apply a y-flip transform if the value of `contentsAreFlipped` is `YES`?

What is the purpose of this property?

Comment: iOS and OS X have different directions for Y.